# Unable to get Set-Cookies header from a Django API

Tags: django, reactjs, api, axios

I am getting these errors when I am trying to hit a Django API.
I have used ReactJS for Frontend and DjangoREST for Backend.

When withCredentials is set False, I got this error.

> Failed to load https://retailo-dot-dogwood-keep-190311.appspot.com/admin/: Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
>   login-form.jsx:58

When True, I got this error.

> Failed to load https://retailo-dot-dogwood-keep-190311.appspot.com/admin/: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

I have used Axios and this is my code.

```
     axios.get('https://retailo-dot-dogwood-keep-190311.appspot.com/admin/',{ 
        // withCredentials: true,
     headers: {
     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'include',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     },
    // credentials: 'same-origin',
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the error from React. This is you have to change in Django settings.
You have allow [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) from your Django side.

https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers

please have a look on above link. Change the settings according to that.